# Where is the unofficial toro (most recent) version?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Where is the unofficial toro (most recent) version?  This dev. preview (here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmlP2P7ibZU) has almost nothing working.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices, where you always (should) find a link to the latest version.